# Android - restarting admob ad request

Tags: android, admob

I am using the following code to display an interstitial ad in my Android app:

```
adView = new DfpInterstitialAd(this, "-----------------------------");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And in a nice transition between the menus, I show it using the following code:

```
if(adView.isReady()) adView.show();
```

However it seems like only for the first time this code runs the ad is actually shown.
Am I expected to create a new adRequest every time I show an ad?
With banner ads it works ok since they automatically change every ~60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call adView.loadAd(adRequest) each time you want a new ad.

Assuming you expect to show mulitlpe intersitials from this one Activity I would recommend something like:

```
if(adView.isReady()) {
  adView.show();
  adView.load(new AdRequest());
}
```

That way you are always queuing up the next ad after you have shown the current one.

Answer (score 0):

For newer admob libraries, you should try using:

```
    if (adView.isReady()) {
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```